# Neo4j: Master node(s) in a "split" cluster

Tags: neo4j

Related to Neo4j 1.9.3 HA clustering, our team had a few different interpretations on how master node(s) behave if a HA cluster 'splits' due to a network problem. We're trying to understand the impact on master nodes as well as the branched database that occurs if/when the master cannot deliver updates to the slaves.

Given a 5 node deployment, where a network failure splits things into two groups/sub-clusters:

- Group[A] consists of 2 nodes
- Group[B] consists of 3 nodes

Each member of a given group can communicate with each other, but [A] cannot communicate with [B]. Prior to the split, the original master node (of the 5-node cluster) lived within the new [A] or [B] groups.

Questions:

If the original master node lived within [A] (i.e. in a minority non-quorum group of cluster nodes), will it write lock its database (knowing that it is a branch at this point) until it can rejoin the entire cluster at which time it will honor the newly elected master from [B] (which was able to elect a new master because it had quorum)?

If the original master node lived within [B] (i.e. in a majority quorum group of cluster nodes), will it  continue to allow write’s to its database, while [A] will be writelocked because it will not have a master?  Or is a master elected in [A] even if it doesn’t have a quorum for the whole cluster?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will always be only one master in a Neo4j cluster. Since the cluster is aware of the number of members a master election requires to have a quorum of more than the half. In case of a split in the way you've described the following will happen:

- original master lived in minority partition A: master will degrade to slave and serve only read requests but won't accept writes. Partition B has a quorum and will elect a new master. When partitioning is resolved the former master will continue to work as slave.
- original master lived in majority partition B: master continues to be master and propagates transactions to other members of B. When partitioning is resolved the former members of A will catch up missing transactions.